# Running MongoDB in NodeJS Express project on Centos server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, centos

I have a NodeJS Express project that uses mongoose to access a MongoDB database. When I run the application on my local laptop, it works fine. I want to run it on a Centos VPS hosting.

Without changing anything in the project, I tried `npm start` in the app directory on the server and I get the following error when I try to use the database:

```
(AppDir)/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)

npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! App@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the App@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the App package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls App
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     (AppDir)/npm-debug.log
```

The code in app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
//some other app functionality
module.exports = app;
```

The code in config/database.js:

```
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'mongodb://(DB URL)'
};
```

I use mongoose models to generate, access and edit Collections in the database.
I can't figure out why it won't work but I think maybe it has to do with the fact that the IP address of the server is different from localhost?

Also, I have researched for a solution and someone suggested to change some things in `/etc/mongod.config` but for some reason I can't find it...? The file doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have a running MongoDB service on your server?

Comment: Check of mongod instance is running using `lsof | grep 27017` where 27017 is default port for mongod deamon

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly mongod wasnt running on the server so I did `mongod &` to make it run in the background. That doesn't seem to help since I get the same error message when I try again.

Comment: I guess you are connecting from _ssh_, if so, `mongod &` will not work

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly oh yes I am using SSH, how else am I supposed to make mongod run in the background?

Comment: ok after researching, I tried `service mongod start` and `mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log` and none of these seems to be resolving the same issue.